# Securing a connection using TOR

Tags: java, api, tor

Are there any possible tutorials or libaries that could be used to secure a connection through using TOR? I've looked for some example usage but my research didn't yield any solid results. I came across [this list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/silvertunnel/wiki/TorJavaOverview) of projects but the links dont really seem to lead to libraries or an API.

What i want to do is secure a connection between a client application and a cassandra server by connecting to TOR.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your link is to a dead project : https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel/discussion/962278/thread/83dc2d02/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor works as a proxy running on your localhost and tunneling each request through Tor network. In your application, pass your request through the proxy. Tor proxies SOCKS5 as well as HTTP.